# faint grey border around bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm getting a faint grey border around my navbar, about 1 px wide. I've tried everything but it just wont go away. I've removed the border and box shadow but still no luck.

Here is my html:

```
 <nav class="navbar my-navbar "> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and my css:

```
.my-navbar{

background-image:url('nav.jpg');
margin-bottom:0 ;
 border: 0 !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;

}


.my-navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.my-navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Update: I've added a couple of full width images to the page and those too have this border around them. I've added the image like so:

```
<img class="banner-img" src="banner.jpg" alt="banner"></img>
```

where banner-img is:

```
 .banner-img{
     display: block;
     height: auto;
     max-width:100%;  
     width:100%;
     border:none !important;
 }
```

Comment: I can't see the .my-navbar class in the HTML?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the code so its there now

Comment: Have you got a codepen or plunkr where we can test this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the ID

```
#myNavbar
```

Answer (score 0):

That's true #myNavbar and then border to none or 0.

```
#myNavbar{
border : 0 or none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. 
I created the website on photoshop and exported each layer seperately from there. The method I was using adds a faint border around each layer when it converts it into a jpeg image. 
Im now using the slice tool and the borders are gone. Thanks for the help.